# Do Alkahestry have same limitations like Alchemy? Or some different limitations?

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist-series, fullmetal-alchemist-brotherhood

In FMA Brotherhood, Alchemy's limits were very well defined but the limits of Alkahestry are never mentioned. Is this ever described outside of the TV series, perhaps in other media or interviews? If so, what are these limitations?

Comment: Related: http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/29877/17758

Comment: I'm inclined to suspect there isn't, since the wiki and related sites will usually have information on that sort of thing (even if they're bad at keeping track of references), but I would need to check.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say that the limitations aren't described, not that there aren't any, in case my wording was ambiguous. It seems likely that there are _some_ restrictions.